# Interrogation about SpringJUnit4ClassRunner's default rollback behavior for integration tests

Tags: spring-transactions, spring-test

I am running Spring integration tests - and therefore using `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)` for those tests.

Some of those tests call business classes/methods (i.e. `src/main/java`) annotated with `@Transactional` and those classes/methods manipulate data in database.

I understand that tests classes/methods (i.e. `src/test/java` and `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner`) annotated with `@Transactional` perform a rollback automatically if not specified otherwise.

Now I want to know if that behavior (automatic rollback) is also to be expected for data manipulated from within business classes/methods (i.e. located within `src/main/java`) when I run integration tests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're in luck... I literally just updated the Javadoc for `TransactionalTestExecutionListener` with the following clarifications:

> **Test-managed Transactions**
>
> Test-managed transactions are transactions that are managed declaratively via this listener or programmatically via TestTransaction. Such transactions should not be confused with Spring-managed transactions (i.e., those managed directly by Spring within the ApplicationContext loaded for tests) or application-managed transactions (i.e., those managed programmatically within application code that is invoked via tests). Spring-managed and application-managed transactions will typically participate in test-managed transactions; however, caution should be taken if Spring-managed or application-managed transactions are configured with any propagation type other than REQUIRED or SUPPORTS.
>
> **Enabling and Disabling Transactions**
>
> Annotating a test method with @Transactional causes the test to be run within a transaction that will, by default, be automatically rolled back after completion of the test. If a test class is annotated with @Transactional, each test method within that class hierarchy will be run within a transaction. Test methods that are not annotated with @Transactional (at the class or method level) will not be run within a transaction. Furthermore, tests that are annotated with @Transactional but have the propagation type set to NOT_SUPPORTED will not be run within a transaction.
>
> **Declarative Rollback and Commit Behavior**
>
> By default, test transactions will be automatically rolled back after completion of the test; however, transactional commit and rollback behavior can be configured declaratively via the class-level @TransactionConfiguration and method-level @Rollback annotations.

Note, however, that `TestTransaction` is a new feature in Spring Framework 4.1, but you can try it out in 4.1 RC1 that just got released yesterday. ;)

In the context of your question, the code you're referring to in `src/main/java` would be related to the *Spring-managed or application-managed transactions* mentioned in the Javadoc. In other words, if you don't have any application code that requires new transactions or suspends current transactions (i.e., the test-managed transaction), then changes made by application code will also get rolled back along with the test-managed transaction.

Regards,

Sam (author of the Spring TestContext Framework)